# Hsqldb - execute query from input string

Tags: hsqldb, dbunit

in hsqldb I want to generate a procedure that is returning a cursor and execute a query taken from a varchar input string. Here's the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EXECUTE (
   IN piv_query      VARCHAR(400)
)
BEGIN ATOMIC
    DECLARE pov_output  CURSOR  WITH RETURN FOR piv_query;
    OPEN pov_output;
END;
```

I receive the error:
unexpected token, PIV_QUERY: line 5 / error corde -5581 / State 42581

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.
Impossible to return a cursor as an out variable, and impossible to have something similar to "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE", so I can't run a dynamic query in this way.